# Why isn't try catch blocks catching exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, try-catch

So I have this piece of code that works fine, but if there is an error with the data type the try catch blocks are not working. It appears I am going to have to check all data types before using them to ensure my server doesn't crash.

For instance in the following code, If tokens for some reason wasn't an array, when the error get's thrown, my try catch isn't catching the error. Instead it is crashing the server.

```
router.patch("/updateDeviceToken", checkIfAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("In updating contacts");
    console.log("body", req.body);
    User.findById(req.authId, (error, user) => {
      try {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log("user found");
          return res.status(404).json(error);
        }
        if (!user) return res.status(401).json("User not found");
        if (
          req.body.android &&
          !user.tokens.android.includes(req.body.android)
        ) {
          user.tokens.android.push(req.body.android);
          user
            .save()
            .then((user) => {
              console.log("token updated");
              return res.json("Token updated");
            })
            .catch((error) => res.status(404).json(error));
        } else if (req.body.iOS && !user.tokens.iOS.includes(req.body.iOS)) {
          user.tokens.iOS.push(req.body.iOS);
          user
            .save()
            .then((user) => {
              console.log("token updated");
              return res.json("Token updated");
            })
            .catch((error) => res.status(404).json(error));
        } else {
          console.log("token received but not updated");
          return res.json("Token received but not updated");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(404).json("There was an error");
      }

    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think `404` is the response code you want to return on a server error. You should choose a 5xx response code. Regardless, wouldn't it make sense to set `res.status` in the outermost catch block?

Comment: are you sure the problem is here and not in the checkIfAuthenticated middleware. Your try/catch should handle pretty much any kind of error.

Comment: I yes the console error just happens with regards to the data types in the DB from time. checkifauthenticated is just a method I wrote to decode the users token and verify authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try catch doesnt work well with `then`

Can you change code to use promises with `await / async` ?

You can use try catch with it

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with that as it is easily overlooked in the documentation but For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, you **must** pass them to the next() function, where Express will catch and process them. For example:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile('/file-does-not-exist', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      next(err) // Pass errors to Express.
    } else {
      res.send(data)
    }
  })
})
```

You can also write your custom [error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), long read but it will save you a lot of time.